# Lazy Loading a Youtube Iframe still causing youtube scripts to be loaded on initial page load

Tags: javascript, core-web-vitals

I'm trying to optimize the loading of a youtube video which is at the bottom of a page – well out of the viewport, and must be scrolled to. I'm using the solution proposed here: https://web.dev/iframe-lazy-loading/

The problem is that on page load, in the dev tools network tab all the youtube external scripts are loading, causing a bottle neck. From what i understand, that code shouldn't be triggered at all until scrolling to the video position on the page.

This works fine in Safari, but Chrome desktop it loads everything at once, pretty much neglecting any lazy loading.

```
<iframe loading="lazy" width="560" height="315" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxx" class="lazyload" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script>

if ('loading' in HTMLIFrameElement.prototype) {
  const iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe[loading="lazy"]');

  iframes.forEach(iframe => {
    iframe.src = iframe.dataset.src;
  });
  console.log('Browser supports lazyloading');

} else {
  // Dynamically import the LazySizes library
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src =
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/5.2.2/lazysizes.min.js';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
  console.log('Browser DOES NOT support lazyloading');
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure: Have you checked the `Disable cache` checkbox in the devtools for testing? In your code you are replacing all iframe srcs immediately. Shouldn't you check if the iframe tag (or its parent) comes into view?

Comment: It seems Chrome overscan threshold is rather high. In my tests I put `200vh  div` before `iframe` and resource was fetched immediately. However, when I raised height to `700vh` lazy loading worked completely fine.

Comment: That was it @Aitwar, my iframe was just inside the 1250px threshold so it was loading it right away, even though i had to scroll a decent amount down the page to get to it.